# Should I spend time levelling up all my units?

Tags: final-fantasy-brave-exvius

Now that I'm getting going, I am getting more summons, and thus, more units.

I'd like to know if it's worth me investing time levelling up all my units, by repeating explore areas, or if I should focus on levelling a 'main' party.

The only benefit I can see to levelling up other units, is to fuse them to your main party.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not planning on using a unit long-term, there is not a lot of use for leveling them up. The only reasons to level up any given unit is:

1. To use them in battle.
2. To awaken them (as part of the Awakening Adept [trophy](https://exviuswiki.com/Trophies) requirements).

With that being said, fusing unused units might not be the best use of them. Sure, they can provide some experience to your other units, but there are better ways to earn experience, most notably after unlocking the Vortex. Fusing units you no longer use causes you to lose any progress you've made with their trust master reward. There are typically only two reasons to fuse units:

1. Fusing with a Metal Cactaur: Giving you free experience during fusion is all Metal Cactaurs are for.
2. Fusing duplicate units: Fusing duplicates gives you 5% towards the Trust Master reward. More details can be found [here](https://exviuswiki.com/Basic_Information), in both the Trust Master and Enhance sections.

Comment: +1, but there are other reasons to fuse, at least now. There are other enhancer units, such as pots from the Arena. I also fuse a lot of units from friend summons into non-matching units for extra xp when I already have the trust master reward for that unit.